# I cannot )SAVE in GNU apl

Tags: save, apl

I named my file (WSID nameOfFile), but when I typed )SAVE this comes out:

Unable to )SAVE workspace 'nameOfFile'. No such file or directory

My workspaces are stored in /apl-1.4

Comment: Works for me with GNU APL 1.4 on Ubuntu 14.04. Are you sure your paths are set up correctly (e.g. `LIBREF-0` in `.gnu-apl/preferences`?

Comment: I uncommented them, but )SAVE still does not work.

Comment: Ok. If you're sure the path you want to write to is ok, I have no idea what the problem might be. Since there are not that many GNU APL users on SO (and I suppose this problem won't show up for them, too), it would probably be better to ask this question on [GNU APL's mailing list.](http://savannah.gnu.org/mail/?group=apl) People there are nice, and they will get this sorted out for you.

Comment: And just to be absolutely sure: You did set, say, `LIBREF-0` to an existing directory you have write access to? I.e. you changed `# LIBREF-0 /home/xyz/my-normal-lib` to something like `LIBREF-0 /home/zoomerhimmer/workspaces/`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not work. And it should not, because libraries 0, 1, 2, 6, 7, 8, and 9 are apparently missing and the paths shown for 3, 4, and 5 are (normally) only writable by root.

To make it work:

1. create one of the directories listed, or
2. mention an existing directory in one of the relevant GNU APL 'preferences' files, or
3. use an absolute path, e.g. )SAVE /home/eedjsa/myws.apl   (in my case).

Have look at chapters 1.4 and 1.5 of the following shell command:

info apl

Comment: Thank you. The first one worked. I think I have tried the 3rd before and failed, but I am not sure. Does the check mean that I accept this as the correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

A useful command for this type of issues in GNU APL is )LIBS. It shows the states of the different library numbers, e.g.:

```
          )LIBS
    Library root: /home/eedjsa

    Library reference number mapping:

    ---------------------------------------------------------
    Ref Conf  Path                                State   Err
    ---------------------------------------------------------
     0 BIN   /home/eedjsa/workspaces              missing (2)
     1 BIN   /home/eedjsa/wslib1                  missing (2)
     2 BIN   /home/eedjsa/wslib2                  missing (2)
     3 PSYS  /usr/local/lib/apl/wslib3            present 
     4 PSYS  /usr/local/lib/apl/wslib4            present 
     5 PSYS  /usr/local/lib/apl/wslib5            present 
     6 BIN   /home/eedjsa/wslib6                  missing (2)
     7 BIN   /home/eedjsa/wslib7                  missing (2)
     8 BIN   /home/eedjsa/wslib8                  missing (2)
     9 BIN   /home/eedjsa/wslib9                  missing (2)
    =========================================================
```

Comment: Mine looks exactly likes yours except the username. Does yours work?